# Is it possible to locally delete all the children of a Firebase read only path?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app which can use two different sets of data depending upon if the user has a paid subscription to a service or is unsubscribed. 
If this is structured in Firebase something like:

```
-all items
    - subscribed items
        - item a
        - item b
    - unsubscribed items
        - item x
        - item y
```

Then the app would create a reference to subscribed items or unsubscribed items as appropriate.

If the user moves from an unsubscribed state to a subscribed state, or vice versa, then the app will need to change its reference. However the items in the previous subscription state are now unneeded by the app i.e. if the user uses the app in an unsubscribed state, Firebase will sync items a and b to the device, then the user subscribes and the app starts using items x and y.

The item numbers can run into the tens of thousands, so my question is how can the app delete items a and b in the example provided when it moves to a subscribed state?

The items are all read only and persistenceEnabled  is set to true.

Is it possible to do this? I can't see anything at all that looks like it might be relevant in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: What is the main reason you need the database to be persistent?  You could always remove the observer on the non-needed portion.

Comment: @rMickeyD If the database is not persisted then the items will be stored in memory cache by Firebase. If the user terminates the app then these will be lost, then when the user re-launches the app then if the database is not persisted Firebase will have to re-fetch every item from server to app. As there are tens and tens of thousands of items this will consume network traffic (ok over wifi, but not ok over a cellular connection) and take additional time.

Comment: @rMIckeyD "You could always remove the observer on the non-needed portion." Would that actually remove the items though, from file and from memory, if they had already previously been synched to the device? If so, is that documented somewhere?